# Quais os significados e as origens das expressões "Sossega o pito!" e "Sossega o facho!"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, etimologia, gíria, origem

Minha mãe, minha avó, sempre que eu badernava demais, quando era criança, diziam:

> *Sossega o pito, menino!*

Ou, então:

> *Sossega o facho!*

Eu nunca entendi ao certo o que *pito* e *facho* significavam e de onde essas palavras vem.

Alguém aí saberia dizer?

Comment: Essa eu não conheço... eu conheco _Sossega o facho_

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Verdade! Já ouvi *Sossega o facho* também! Vou atualizar a pergunta com as variações.

Comment: Acho que significa "Está calado". Quanto à origem, não tenho a certeza.

Comment: @someonewithpc A intenção e a conotação, acho que todos que já se depararam com a expressão entendem, principalmente dependendo do tom que a pessoa usa (hahaha)! Mas acho válido tentar entender mais a fundo o significado em sua raíz!

Comment: Porquê a tag [tag:brasileirismo]?

Comment: @E_net4 Porque acredito que seja algo do Brasil. Por imaginar tal peculiaridade, adicionei a tag `brasileirismo`. Veja a definição na wikipedia: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brasileirismo

Comment: @E_net4 Sabe se esta expressão também ocorre em outros países de língua portuguesa?

Comment: @falsarella Por acaso, já poderei ter ouvido a primeira expressão em Portugal. Mas independentemente disso, já temos a tag [tag:brasil]. Se for para acrescentar outra, há que se estabelecer porquê.

Comment: @E_net4 OK. Seu questionamento é bem pertinente. Assim que eu tiver um tempinho eu levo esta dúvida ao [meta](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/). Obrigado!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Procurei na internet, e em lugar algum fala algo sobre a origem, todos apenas do significado. Mas depois de várias pesquisas e muito pensamento lógico, me surgiu uma teoria que acho que até que faz um pouco de sentido sobre a origem de "sossega o facho".

Primeiramente, "sossegar/abaixar o facho/pito" significa aquietar-se, acalmar-se.<sup><sup>1, 2</sup></sup>

Tendo isso em mente, vamos começar primeiro com "facho".

### Facho

Facho vem do latim "*fax*" que significa "tocha", "archote", "luzeiro", etc.<sup><sup>1, 2, 3, 4</sup></sup>
Facho também significa "vegetação seca facilmente inflamável". <sup><sup>4</sup></sup>
Ou seja, fachos queimam.

Em inglês, um possível equivalente de "sossegar o facho" é "simmer down", que significa "tornar-se mais calmo e quieto, após ter estado em grande raiva ou agitação".<sup><sup>5</sup></sup>
"Simmer" pode significar "cozinhar em fogo brando".<sup><sup>6</sup></sup> Então *simmer down* também pode ter uma ideia de "abaixar/diminuir o fogo".

Alguns dos significados metafóricos de "fogo" são "energia, vivacidade, agitação, desassossego, entusiasmo", etc.<sup><sup>7</sup></sup>

Pode-se também pensar na possibilidade de a pessoa ser assemelhada com um facho, na expressão, como se ela, o alvo, fosse uma tocha com fogo (agitação).

Com tudo isso, pode-se chegar à conclusão de que "sossegar o facho", significa "acalmar/abaixar/diminuir o [fogo do] facho".

"Sossegar o facho" não é usado em Portugal.<sup><sup>2</sup></sup>

### Pito

Quanto a "pito", aí já é mais complicado dizer, porque "pito" tem  algumas diferenças no significado entre o português europeu e o brasileiro, como é possível ver [aqui](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pito). Mas como foi salientado abaixo pelos colegas, não sei quanto ao Brasil, mas pelo menos em Portugal, "pito" seria uma palavra para "órgão genital feminino", assim como o "periquita" que também tem esse significado. Seria o mesmo que "sossega a periquita!".

"Sossegar o pito" significa "quietar/sossegar", sexualmente ou não (quando dito em relação a um adulto ou uma criança, por exemplo).

<sub>Fontes:

1. [Portoweb](http://www2.portoalegre.rs.gov.br/pwcidadao/default.php?reg=95&p_secao=158), 2. [Dicionário Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/facho), 3. [Dicionário Latim-Português](https://pt.glosbe.com/la/pt/fax), 4. [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/facho), 5. [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/simmer+down),

6. [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-portuguese/simmer), 7. [Michaellis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/fogo%20_967421.html)</sub>

Comment: Ótima linha de pesquisa! Seguindo sua lógica, `pito` poderia significar o fogo queimando do cigarro/charuto/cachimbo de forma semelhante/análoga ao `facho`. Faz muito sentido! +1!

Comment: Pode ser também, só que aí precisaria ter uma labareda no cachimbo/cigarro pra fazer mais sentido, né.

Comment: Sim, subentende-se que ele está aceso.

Comment: "pito" vem do órgão sexual feminino. Diz-se em Portugal *"sossega o pito, parece que estás com o pito aos saltos"* . Não sei de onde vem, mas parece ser de alguém que está com "fogo" sexual e para se acalmar. Então será uma analogia também.

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim, também pensei nesse significado, mas não tinha certeza se teria algo a ver e não queria arriscar falar bobagem. Mas pelo que vocês dizem, parece ser esse mesmo o significado.

Comment: Mas o significado é o mesmo, para te acalmares

Comment: @JorgeB. Ok, adicionei essa informação na resposta.

Answer (score 6):

Em Portugal, `sossega o pito` significa "acalma-te".
Pito é usado com o significado de [órgão sexual feminino](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/pito), equivalente a "acalma a passarinha".

Não é usada a expressão `sossega o facho`.

Answer (score 4):

***Sossegar o facho, assentar o facho, abaixar o facho*** e ***apagar o facho*** são apresentados como sinónimos pelo [Aulete digital na entrada ***facho***](http://www.aulete.com.br/facho):

> ***Abaixar o facho*** **1** Bras. Fam. Diminuir ou ter diminuído o entusiasmo, a vitalidade; apagar o facho; assentar o facho; sossegar o facho

Em particular a versão ***apagar o facho*** sugere apagar uma tocha ou archote, que é a primeira definição de *facho* no Aulete. Mesmo *baixar o facho* sugere-me facho no sentido de archote: pelo menos em Portugal dizemos *baixar o lume* quando reduzimos uma chama num fogão. De resto ***facho*** tem também um sentido figurado relevante, muito usado na literatura do século XIX. Citando de novo o [Aulete em ***facho***](http://www.aulete.com.br/pito):

> **5** Fig. Tudo que serve como elemento para suscitar, alimentar ou desenvolver qualquer paixão: "Uma palavra inflamada agitava no ânimo da tropa o facho do ódio ao governo." (Rui Barbosa, *Ditadura e república*)

Portanto parece-me que a ideia de reduzir a chama dum facho, no sentido literal ou figurado, é uma inspiração plausível para as expressões *apagar o facho, sossegar o facho*, etc..

Quando a ***sossegar o pito***, sob a entrada [***pito*** no Aulete digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/pito) aparece:

> **1** Bras. Cachimbo
>
> ***De pito aceso*** Excitado, irrequieto, agitado.
>
> ***Sossegar o pito*** Acalmar-se, sossegar (quem está agitado, excitado)

Este [artigo sobre o cigarro na cultura popular do Rio Grande do Sul](http://www.jangadabrasil.com.br/fevereiro30/cn30020c.htm), onde pito também significa cigarro, apresenta, para além de *de pito aceso* e *sossega o pito*, a seguinte expressão:

> ***Estar de pito apagado***:  estar triste, abatido, jururu.

Este artigo apresenta o cigarro como a inspiração das três expressões. Cigarro ou cachimbo, esta é para mim também a explicação mais plausível: cigarro ou cachimbo aceso significaria excitação; se se reduz a intensidade com que ardem, significaria acalmar. A interpretação é portanto a mesma que no caso do facho, como sugerido pelo bfavaretto num comentário a outra resposta.

Quem sabe até se não houve já uma associação entre a ideia de cachimbo e cigarro por um lado e facho por outro, o que poderia ter facilitado o aparecimento de uma expressão por inspiração na outra. Eu encontrei estas duas passagens:

> — Pois canta o cigarro. Admitte-se o culto. Vae entoando a antiphona, emquanto nós accendemos os fachos do rito sagrado — respondeu Philippe, distribuindo cigarros por todos os da cavalgada. (Júlio Diniz, *Serões da Província*, 1869.)
>
> Apago o meu charuto quando apagas teu facho, ó sol. (Antero de Quental, “Velut Umbra,” in *Primaveras Românticas*, 1872.)

A interpretação sexual de *sossega o pito* é extremamente grosseira, o que não quer dizer que não possa estar na origem da expressão. Também é possível que haja duas origens diferentes, uma no Brasil, outra em Portugal. Ainda existe a possibilidade de haver uma única origem com reinterpretação posterior. Por exemplo, a expressão poderia inspirar-se no cachimbo no Brasil, vir para Portugal, onde se prestaria a ganhar uma interpretação sexual. Devo dizer no entanto que nunca tinha ouvido essa expressão. Pode ser apenas regional: eu sou da zona de Lisboa; o Jorge e o ANeves, que ja conheciam a expressão, são do norte. Mas curiosamente o meu Dicionário Universal da Lello e Irmão, uma editora portuense, apresenta *de pito aceso* e *sossegar o pito* como brasileirismos.